# This app is incompatible with your device

Tags: android, tablet

I have just made an android application tested on "HUAWEI T1-701u" AND  "HUAWEI T1-A21L", i have generated a signed apk and it's now published on the play store, 
the problem is the app just working on anything i have expect HUAWEI T1-701u even i tested on it, it says something like this: app is not compatible with this device, even i tested on it. 
here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="100" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

and here is the gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.iowpjordan.mpic"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Please note that the screen size of HUAWEI T1-701u is 7 inch and the other one is 10 approximately

Please advice.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the features in manifest are too sensitive if do you put a useless feature and you don't have it on your phone then the app will not be compatible with your phone 
if you are not using Autofocus,remove this line `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />`
 because the phone which are you testing on, doesn't have autofocus feature! that's why the app will not be compatible with your device

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned targetSdkVersion 19 in build.gradle file.
It will work for only kitkat devices.

What is the android version of the device that you are testing?

Comment: it's 4.4.2 same with my second device but has smaller screen